# Any machine learning algorithm perform better than Time Series Analysis for seasonal signals?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, splines

For example, consider training samples based on daily sales of a superstore during the last few years. We are pretty sure there are seasonal factors.

With Time Series Analysis, one firstly have to de-seasonal for the sales, and then do a regression on a curve without any seasonal signal, and finally multiply the seasonal factor back.

Is there any regression method without going through any deseasonal process, but provide even better accuracy in predicting the future daily sales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been very successful in analyzing daily sales by building a super-regression model which incorporates user specified predictors ( e.g. price/weather/promotions_ and day-of-the-week effects/week-of-the-year effects/month-of-the-year effects/week-of-the month effects . These models can also include holiday ( pre and post effects ) , day-of-the-month effects along with ARIMA structure and both trends and level shift effects while also identifying pulses. You can look at http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/53-capabilities-presentation particularly slides 45-57 to get an idea about this. The modelling strategy is called Transfer Functions and/or Dynamic Regression.

Comment: It looks very interesting. Is there any open-source algorithm in R or Python, so that we can adapt it to our need?

Comment: Automatic Forecasting Systems has an R Version. You can get their contact info from the AUTOBOX website.